# PHP Cookies problem... cookie working on one page but not working on another

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

Hi can anyone explain this to me:

On one page I have:

```
setcookie(cookiename,$cookiedata,time()+(84600*30*24));
setcookie(cookiename2,$cookie2data, time()+(84600*30*24));
```

If on the same page i say:

```
echo $_COOKIE['cookiename'];
```

it works fine....

but if i go to a page which is a few clicks onwards, and say:

```
echo $_COOKIE['cookiename'];
```

nothing appears. Why does this happen? is the cookie deleted in some way?

oh and if you try it on the page in between, the same problem occurs.... I'm stumped,

Thanks in advance, 
Niall

Comment: Use something like HTTPFox and/or Firebug to view the client<->server communications. You'd be able to view the cookie headers going back and forth, and see exactly where/when they vanish on you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are the different pages on the same domain?  You should also be setting a path, I have found cases when the path was not set to '/' then it would not be accessible by default 'everywhere' on the site even though that would make sense as the default.

Try setting the path of the cookie.

Comment: In fact, php::setcookie() states that the default 'path' is the current directory that the cookie is being set it, that is the problem.  Set the path to '/'

Comment: Ok that sounds right yes. I didn't set the path and they are in different places, thanks :)